# How do I use implicit differentiation?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have to find the derivative of $y=\cos^{-1}(11 x^{12})$.

Should I use implicit differentiation with respect to x here, or is there another way to go about this?

Comment: is this $$y=arccos(11x^{12})$$?

Comment: I think so, because cos^-1 is arccos, right?

Comment: yes i also think so shuold i post the derivative with respect to $x$?

Comment: sure! thank you for your help

Comment: You can use either way. I think what you are calling implicit differentiation is more straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

5xum is right. You should use chain rule.

$$y=cos^{-1}(11x^{12})$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{d}{dx}[cos^{-1}(11x^{12})]=[\frac{d}{d(11x^{12})}(cos^{-1}(11x^{12}))]\frac{d}{dx}(11x^{12})$$
$$=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-121x^{24}}}\cdot 132x^{11}$$
$$=-\frac{132x^{11}}{\sqrt{1-121x^{24}}}$$

Comment: thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 2):

You could, as in $\cos y(x) = 11 x^{12}$, then
$-\sin y(x) {d y(x) \over dx } = 132 x^{11}$.

Then we compute $\sin y(x) = \sqrt{1-\cos^2 y(x)} = \sqrt{1-(11 x^{12})^2}$ (we take the positive root because of the way $\arccos$ is defined).

Answer (score 1):

You don't use implicit differentiation, you use the chain rule, i.e. the rule that $(f\circ g)' = (f'\circ g) \cdot g'$

In your case, $f(x) = \cos^{-1}(x)$ and $g(x) = 11x^{12}$.

Comment: @HoseynHeydari Actually, the link you provided shows quite clearly that if you have $y=f(x)$, then calculating $y'=f'(x)$ is **not** implicit differentiation. Implicit differentiation means that you start with $f(x,y)=0$, calculate $y'\cdot \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 0$, and calculate $y'$ from that.

Answer (score 1):

Using the chain rule to find the derivative of $arccos$ we get
$$y'(x)=-\frac{132 x^{11}}{\sqrt{1-121 x^{24}}}$$